# Como substituir dentro de uma string uma substring por outra?

Tags: php

Encontrei na documentação do `PHP` a função `substr_replace` mas ela não faz exatamente o que eu quero, ela simplesmente substitui uma string que eu passo como parâmetro por outra substring. O que eu quero é passar uma string e dentro dessa string substituir todas as ocorrências de uma determinada substring por outra.

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso, a função que você precisa é a `str_replace`, que substitui todas ocorrências de uma string por outra em uma string.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
echo str_replace("mundo", "Júlio", "Olá mundo!");
?>
```

Este código irá trocar a palavra `"mundo"` por `"Júlio"` na string `"Ola mundo!"` e irá imprimir: `Olá Júlio`.

Referência oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Verdade, e essa mesma, tava dificil de achar aquele manual e uma bagunca, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode utilizar a função `strtr ("hello my name is santa", array ('hello' => 'ola'));`

Neste caso toda ocorrência `'hello'` será trocada por `'olá'`.

Se quiser alterar mais de um valor, é possível incluir mais itens no array de parâmetros:

```
strtr ("hello my name is santa", array ('hello' => 'ola', 'is' => 'é'));
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php

Comment: Com essa funcao eu posso pesquisar por mais de uma substring? Se sim ela sera bem util.

Comment: @JúlioSouzaPereira sim, você pode colocar quantos argumentos quiser dentro do array. Vou melhorar a resposta.